# Is it possible to move from an old mac to a new mac only selected applications and documents?

Tags: migration, migration-assistant

I would like to move from an old mac book pro to a new one only selected applications and documents. I set my old mac using an older one mac so I have very old applications that I should uninstall. I run migration assistant but with this program is not possible to select the application I want to transfer. Is there another way to do this? Both mac (old and new) run Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course select and copy any documents you want: though you will have to select them manually.

For the applications, it will largely depend on where they came from. Apps from the Mac App Store are linked to your Apple ID, and can be re-downloaded from the App Store onto the new Mac.

Third-party software may work just by copying the application: though some apps may need an installer that adds additional support files. Apps may need serial numbers or other protection re-applied.

whether they are App Store downloads, or other software that requires an installer. Some apps can be copied